How to upload and edit image in wwwroot folder in asp.net mvc 8.0 with sql server
I am new to learning asp .net and have a small project that has a book management function that implements CRUD. I save the data type for images as string in sql server and the same in the model. The images folder is saved in wwwroot, now I don't know how to upload new images and edit them. Hope I get suggestions from everyone. thank you very much
public int BookId { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

public string Author { get; set; } = null!;

public string Publisher { get; set; } = null!;

public int YearPublished { get; set; }

public int CategoryId { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public int Available { get; set; }

public string BookImage { get; set; } = null!;

public virtual ICollection<BorrowReturn> BorrowReturns { get; set; } = new List<BorrowReturn>();

public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;

public virtual ICollection<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; } = new List<Statistic>();

I tried with video tutorials but most of them are version 5.0 and there are some libraries they don't support in version 8.0

I trust you are now having an .net 8 MVC web application which implement a file-uploading feature, so that this document should contain the tutorial and sample codes you required except the edit image part, as I don't understand what kind of editing you are trying to do. By the way, we usually store the image path into the database, and the image itself is stored in server disk. When we require to show the image in website, we just need to get the image file path and put it in <img src="path" />.

Here's a simple sample for asp.net core MVC application to upload an image and display it.
Controller and model:
public class FileController : Controller
{

public IActionResult ImageUpload(string? path)
{
    ImageUpload model = new ImageUpload { filePath = path };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ImageUpload mod)
{

    if (mod.file.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images", mod.file.FileName);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await mod.file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ImageUpload", new { path = "/images/" + mod.file.FileName });
}
}

public class ImageUpload {
    public string? filePath { get; set; }

    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}

My ImageUpload.cshtml
@model WebAppMvc.Controllers.ImageUpload

<form action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <img src=@(Model.filePath==null?null:Model.filePath) />
    <input asp-for="file" type="file">

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>



If we need to store the file path into database, just ad DB operation within the  post method. If we need to display the image when the page is loading, just querying DB in the Get method.

@user23785104   Does my post help solve your problems? And do you have any other questions? Please feel free to let me know if I didn't understand your questions completely.

oh I'm really sorry I forgot to reply to you, I thank you very much for your article it helped me solve the problem. <3
